# Voice on calls are too quiet

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, calls, sony-xperia-z2

I got a new phone and sometimes it's hard to hear the person on the other line. Sometimes people say it's hard to hear me. This is a high end phone and I don't think this should be happening. What options are available to change? I've pressed the volume-up arrow to the top when I'm on a call and it's still too quiet.

What exactly do the options: Speaker voice enhancement, equalizer and microphone noise suppression do?

Answer (score 2):

Audio volume during phone calls appears to be a common complaint made by many Sony users.

I recommend turning off all the extras/enhancements to make a final determination regarding call volume. A different device may be better for you.

Below are the various options described:

- Speaker Voice Enhancement provides "richer" voice listening during
  phone calls (impacts what you hear). Turn this off.
- Equalizer fine tunes the pitch of the call audio (impacts what you
  hear). Turn this off or choose the most level/smooth option.
- Phone Noise Suppression reduces background noise on your end (impacts
  what other people hear). Turn this off if other people can't hear you
  or experience breaks/skips in your voice. This feature may be useful
  when you are outside.
- Enhanced Voice Privacy provides an additional layer of voice
  encryption (impacts both sides of conversation). Turn this off if the
  option is available.

Answer (score 1):

After many months of suffering that others cant hear me, i found whats wrong with my Z2.
Go to settings - sound&notification - Accessory settings - Mic sensitivity
Set it to "High"
Auto does not work good for me...
Yes I know that it looks like this seting is for acessories.. but no, its for internal mic, you can test it in settings - about phone - diagnostics - test - microphone.. change mic sensitivity and try this test.. on high you can hear yourself back.. on low you almost can't hear yourself back.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this problem  :It is a bug in the xperia software, which lowers your call speaker volume also whenever u connect a headphone for phone call and reduces it's volume.

Solution :connect a headphone. Call someone and maximize the volume. Then, remove the headphone and see that your call speaker also has maximum volume.